# Find all points on the line 9x-21y=6

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

[image]For this equation we are suppose to use the Euclidean Algorithm. But I run into a problem

For the GCD (9,-21)=

i tried 
9=(-21)(0)+9 
-21=9(3)+6
9=6(1)+3
6=3(2) +0

which gives a gcd of 3 and the weights (4,1) But this gives me the wrong x and y when 
x=x not b/d t for b =-21 and d =3 and t for any integer.

Please help

Comment: Please show exactly what you did. What does `(-21)(0)+9 -21` mean? Why did you write that?

Comment: i set 9=-21 and -21 goes into 9 0 times with a remainder of 9. For the Euclidean Algorithm if you continue this process and set -21=9 and 9 goes into -21 three times with a remainder of +6

Comment: sorry its kind of hard to type in numbers let me try and take a picture of my work    Or i guess that brings another question of whether  GCD(a,-b) makes sense even if there is a negative in there or not?

Comment: Just figured it out and posted a picture of my work, thanks for responding

Comment: $y=\frac{3x-2}{7}$.